# Inspect .h5 file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, h5py

I have an issue regarding an .h5 file, which I don't really know what it contains. Actually, I want to check what is inside the file using Python, but every time I open it with pandas:

```
df = pd.read_hdf('file.h5')
```

it returns an error:

```
ValueError: No dataset in HDF5 file.
```

Any idea how to successfully open and inspect it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas is more of a library for CSV or other delimiter separated values.

So, use `h5py`.

```
>>> import h5py
>>> f = h5py.File('mytestfile.h5', 'r')
```

The File object is your starting point .h5py.File acts like a Python dictionary, thus we can check the keys,

```
>>> list(f.keys())
['mydataset']
```

Based on our observation, there is one data set, mydataset in the file. Let us examine the data set as a Dataset object

```
>>> dset = f['mydataset']
```

The object we obtained isn’t an array, but an HDF5 dataset. Like NumPy arrays, datasets have both a shape and a data type:

```
>>> dset.shape
(100,)
>>> dset.dtype
dtype('int32')
```

They also support array-style slicing. This is how you read and write data from a dataset in the file:

```
>>> dset[...] = np.arange(100)
>>> dset[0]
0
>>> dset[10]
10
>>> dset[0:100:10]
array([ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
```

Comment: When I tried `list(f.keys())`, I got this error: `TypeError: h5py objects cannot be pickled`. Can anyone help me?